# Visual Studio Express 2012 and Typescript output directory

Tags: visual-studio-2012, typescript

I've successfully installed the typescript plugin into the VS.
I would like to change to compiled js files output directory. Currently the js files are being  in the same directory with the ts files.
I found a solution that said I should install web essentials and with that I can modify the compiler settings. Unfortunately, the free VS express don't let me to install 3rdparty things. It's ok, but is there any other solution to change the output directory of js files?
In command line it IS a simple --out flag.

Comment: I would like to shamelessly point out that you can use https://github.com/basarat/grunt-ts :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I've solved the problem.

The solution:
I added these lines into the csproj file:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <TypeScriptCompile Include="$(ProjectDir)\**\*.ts" />
 </ItemGroup>
 <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <Exec Command="&quot;$(PROGRAMFILES)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\tsc&quot; @(TypeScriptCompile ->'&quot;%(fullpath)&quot; --outDir myoutputdirectory', ' ')" />
 </Target>
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm not familiar with the limitations of Express, but here's how you do it in the Pro edition without Web Essentials:

Open up the `.csproj` file inside your project with your favorite text editor.  Look for the property groups that look like:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">
    ...
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
    ...
</PropertyGroup>
```

and inside both of those add a property like so:

```
<TypeScriptOutDir>my/dir</TypeScriptOutDir>
```

If you open up `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets` you can see how those properties map to the command line flags and how I figured it out.

Like I said I don't know Express and whether it places any limitations on modifying `.csproj` files so let me know if this works.

Answer (score 4):

not need edit .csproj file, just go to project properties and set "Redirect JavaScript output to directory"

[image: easy way]

Answer (score 2):

The TypeScript compiler has a flag to redirect output to a directory:

```
tsc --outDir "Path" app.ts
```

Comment: Yes I know it, but how and where can I set this in visual studio?

Comment: You mentioned the `--out` flag in your question, which combines output into a single file, so I thought you didn't know about `--outDir`, which redirects output to a directory.

Answer (score 1):

I have this problem in typescript 1.8, after google a little I discovered that the following Output options in the typescript properties project page are incompatible.

- If you select **Combine Javascript output into file** then if you
  want to put the .js and .map file in other file, you must to put here
  the directory, and do **not** select **Redirect Javascript output
  directory**
- In the other hand if you want to have individual .js files and move
  them to a specific directory, then select  **Redirect Javascript
  output directory** and maintain deselected **Combine Javascript
  output into file**

For example in my case I want to have a combined .js in a specific directory then may setting are as show in the picture:

[image: Here I entered my directory and my combined java-script file in **Combine JavaScript output into file**]